# Tipps for a better performance on a C# code

Tags: c#, performance

I wrote a small program to calculate the total value of some items in the Steam market. Everything works fine but the program needs around 2 minutes to start, it's because it took some time to get the price of the items.
Now I would like to know if I could change the code a little bit to optimize the program so it doesn't take 2 minutes to start, maybe 1 or less would be great.

Between each connection to the website where I get the prices, I have to wait a few seconds (around 3,5 sec seems to be the best), or I get an error because of too many requests, so this is a thing I think I can't really change.

This is how I get the price from the website:

```
string urlsteammarkt = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=";
string Chroma()
        {
            WebClient chroma = new WebClient();
            //get the informations
            srcChroma = chroma.DownloadString(urlsteammarkt + "Chroma%20Case");
            //cute out the min price
            srcChroma = srcChroma.Remove(0, 32);
            srcChroma = srcChroma.Remove(srcChroma.IndexOf('\\'));
            //replace -- when it's a round price (e.g. 13€ will be displayed as 13,--)
            srcChroma = srcChroma.Replace("--", "00");

            return srcChroma + "€\n";
        }
```

Code is too long, here is the rest of the code:
https://pastebin.com/ZrTqjMd0

Comment: If you are so concerned with performance, why are you using WebClient? According to its documentation it became obsolete when HttpClient was introduced with .NET 4.5 in 2012 and should not be used anymore since that date.

Comment: If you make a new web request for each item that might be causing a slow down. Maybe research how to query the prices for all items in a single request.

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/ZrTqjMd0) is more than a program. It is a copy-paste masterpiece! :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you are literally telling your program to sleep (just wait and do nothing).

And you need to learn programming, especially oop (https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_oop.asp)